# Can I show keyboard when alert is displayed?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad

My app shows alert and if user didn't dismiss it then app can show another view under this alert. This new view contains text field and the problem is I'm calling becomeFirstResponder on this field but keyboard doesn't show. My question is if there is any possibility to show keyboard when alert is shown? I guess this makes sense to not show keyboard until alert is dismissed - it probably is default iOS SDK behaviour to block keyboard but this was reported to me by customer as an issue... Can someone more experienced help me?

Note: this is different than following problem as I don't have text field inside alert but instead its on view under alert.
[UIAlertView keyboard doesn't get shown unless app is re-opened](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11563461/uialertview-keyboard-doesnt-get-shown-unless-app-is-re-opened)

Answer (score 0):

you can open keyboard while alert, but for it you have to add testFiled on alertview and make it FirstResponder